# Domain name validation regex - how to expand into multiline validation?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Here is my current situation; I am a near complete regexp illiterate, and have been tasked with expanding a slice of our website that requests a domain name from the user for a customer account. Right now it is one line, one domain name, and the below regexp works great.

```
(?i)^(?!.{257,})(?!.*-\\.)(?!.*?-\\.)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,64}\\.)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,6})\\b
```

What I need to do is allow the user to input multiple domain names in the box. One per line. Basically all I need to do is wrap this regexp so that is applies the validation line by line, rather than on the entire set.

I know this thing uses negative look aheads, though what those are I have no real idea. Every tutorial I find seems to skirt the ideas an concepts that I need. Any ideas, links, or comments that I can study this weekend would be most appreciated.

By the way, I am implementing this in .Net MVC 3.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the easiest thing to do would be to split the list of domains from each line into a list and then run the existing regex over each domain individually.  That way if one is invalid, you can tell them the domain on line XX is not valid, whereas if you tried to make that work on a huge list you wouldn't easily be able to tell where it failed.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, worked out great. Also, because I changed the way I was looking at it, my UI design looks and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Regexp frameworks provide a set of extended options that modify the overall behavior of matching.

The following two links contain references for .NET and Javascript:

- [.NET Regexp Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx)
- [JavaScript Regexp Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

In both cases the *m* option might be what you're looking for if the entire multi-line string gets fed into the regular expression.

Also, as far as negative look-aheads are concerned, this little snippet from the Python regexp module gives a concise example (from [Python Regex Module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)):

> (?!...)
>
> Matches if ... doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?!Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s not followed by 'Asimov'.